# How to identify different test cases when parameterizing

Tags: java, junitparams

When using JUnitParams, I can pass an array of `Objects` where each element will be used to run a test.

Is there any way to add a name or identification to each of these? So when I run these JUnit test, Eclipse would show the name of each case instead of the 0-n index of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`JUnitParams` supports custom test names using the `@TestCaseName` annotation that would accomplish what you want. The annotation allows you to pass a template for the test name and then use indexed parameters in the format `{n}`.

Heres a very simple example of how that would work:

```
@Test
@Parameters(...)
@TestCaseName("Test {0} equals {1}")
public void testName(String expected, String actual) {
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Reference:

- [JUnitParams/TestCaseName.java](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/main/java/junitparams/naming/TestCaseName.java)
- [Many examples on programcreek.com](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=junitparams.naming.TestCaseName)